# alterar cor de conteúdo de acordo com valores na tabela

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

alguém podendo me ajudar agradeço

Eu recebo valores no formato ex: 5/7 é o resultado do placar que o usuário cadastra e pode visualizar na mesma tela, se eu tivesse apenas o numero acredito que o JS iria pegar isso num int e ficaria fácil minha lógica rodar, mas como temos ai uma barra o JS ja vira para um string.

```
<td>
     <span class="placares">${listaResultados.placar1}/${listaResultados.placar2}</span>
     <span class="placares">${listaResultados.placar3}/${listaResultados.placar4}</span>
     <span class="placares">${listaResultados.placar5}/${listaResultados.placar6}</span>
     <span class="placares">${listaResultados.placar7}/${listaResultados.placar8}</span>
     <span class="placares">${listaResultados.placar9}/${listaResultados.placar10}</span>
 </td>
```

na minha logica aqui embaixo eu vou pegando todos esses textos "5/7 ou 6/3 e etc..." e inicialmente preciso tirar essa "/" separar esses valores para depois compara-los se o primeiro número for maior quero essa classe "badge badge-warning" adicionada e do contrário quero um outro badge.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var spans = $(".placares");
spans.each(function(i, val) {
    var valores = getValores(val.textContent);
    if(valores.primeiroNumero > valores.segundoNumero) {
        $(val).removeAttr('').addClass('badge badge-info');
        return
    }
    if(valores.primeiroNumero < valores.segundoNumero) {
        $(val).removeAttr('').addClass('badge badge-warning');
        return
    }

})

function getValores(texto) {
    var split = texto.split('/');
    return {
        primeiroNumero: parseInt(split[0], 10),
        segundoNumero: parseInt(split[1], 10)
    };
}</script>
```

Alguém me ajudar nesse JS? 
ele não funciona!!!
não tenho nenhum erro na console do browser.

Comment: E qual seria o problema se não tem erro?

Comment: caramba, q idiota eu fui agora
simplesmente esse javascript não funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está um pouco grande para pouca coisa a fazer. Sugiro o seguinte código que irá adicionar as `class` de acordo os valores nos `spans` e remover a `class placares`:

```
var spans = $(".placares");
spans.each(function(i, val) {
   var valores = val.textContent;
   valores = valores.split('/').map(Number);
   $(val).addClass(valores[0] > valores[1] ? 'badge badge-info' : 'badge badge-warning')
   .removeClass('placares');
});
```

**Veja:**

Coloquei `background` apenas como ilustração:

```js
var spans = $(".placares");
spans.each(function(i, val) {
   var valores = val.textContent;
   valores = valores.split('/').map(Number);
   $(val).addClass(valores[0] > valores[1] ? 'badge badge-info' : 'badge badge-warning')
   .removeClass('placares');
});
```

```css
.badge-info{
   background: orange;
}

.badge-warning{
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
           <span class="placares">5/7</span>
           <span class="placares">6/3</span>
           <span class="placares">2/1</span>
           <span class="placares">3/4</span>
           <span class="placares">7/4</span>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```